# Application Registration stops working in Azure DevOps, despite "Basic" license being assigned

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an Application Registration setup, and am using it to programtically read some information from Azure DevOps using the REST APIs.

This worked fine - i'd setup the App Registration, and granted it a "Basic" license at the organizational level in Azure DevOps.
I was then able to use the App Registration to scan through some repositories after granting it the "Project Reader" role on those projects.
[image: organization settings showing the user having basic license applied]
[image: manage access dialog showing user has project readers role on some projects]
[image: dialog showing api permissions in azure entra id]

However, a few days later, and this automation stopped working.
The only way to fix it, is to completely remove the user from the DevOps Organization and re-add them. No amount of changing or re-assigning licenses, project permissions or otherwise resolves the issue.

In this case, access lasted 9 days. In previous cases, it lasted 7 - 9 days also.
The date shown (15th of February) as the "Last accessed date" is the last date that this worked correctly, which may indicate it's not connecting properly?

I can't see any error when trying to access the REST APIs, in fact, it shows the account being connected properly... However, it's not able to access anything.

Any ideas on this one?

EDIT:
Here's the powershell function where i grab the access token from the auth endpoint:

```
function Get-BearerTokenFromDevOps ([string]$secret) {
    $body = @{
        client_id     = $clientId
        scope         = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default" #API Permission: Azure Devops "User Impersonation", value of Resource App ID & /.default
        client_secret = $secret
        grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    }
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT REMOVED>/oauth2/v2.0/token" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body
    if ($null -ne $result.access_token) {
        return $result.access_token.ToString()
    } else {
        Write-Error "Received invalid response to OAuth query. Terminating script..."
        throw
    }
}
```

I then call this code specifically to grab the user i'm authenticated as for use in other calls:

```
function Get-AuthenticatedUserId {

    $connectedUser = Get-FromDevOpsURL "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/ConnectionData"

    if ($null -ne $connectedUser -and $null -ne $connectedUser.Content) {
        $connectedUser = ConvertFrom-Json $connectedUser.Content
        return $connectedUser.authenticatedUser.id
    }
}
```

After that, i grab the 'account list' from DevOps (Contains info about which organizations the user object has access to):

```
function Get-AccountListFromDevOps([string]$userId) {
    $accountsListResponse = Get-FromDevOpsURL "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/accounts?api-version=6.0&memberId=$userId"
    if ($null -ne $accountsListResponse -and $null -ne $accountsListResponse.Content) {
        $accountsListResponse = ConvertFrom-Json $accountsListResponse.Content
        return $accountsListResponse.value
    }
}
```

And a function you'll see a few times:

```
function Get-FromDevOpsURL($url)
{
        if ($null -eq $clientSecret)
        { 
            throw
        }

        if($null -eq $script:bearerToken)
        {
            Write-Host "Getting Bearer Token"
            $script:bearerToken = (Get-BearerTokenFromDevOps -secret $clientSecret)
        }
        $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $script:bearerToken" }
        $response = $(Invoke-WebRequest $url -Headers $headers)

    return $response
}
```

EDIT2: Trying to reproduce this with the setup provided by Ziyang Liu in the comments below, results in the following error message being shown when trying to retrieve a list of APIs:

> Invoke-RestMethod: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"A
> claim of type
> 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
> or
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider'
> was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery
> token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the
> configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the
> ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims
> provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier,
> it can be configured by setting the static property
> AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.","typeName":"System.InvalidOperationException,
> mscorlib","typeKey":"InvalidOperationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

Here's a screenshot of the code suggested by Ziyang Liu being run in Powershell 7.4:
[image: Screenshot of code being run in powershell 7.4.1 and encountering error]

Comment: I am currently unable to reproduce your issue when using a service principal. But I encountered a similar situation before when using the managed identity to call REST API in function app. Are you using a service principal in a function app or somewhere else? Please refer to [this ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-access-Azure-DevOps-using-API-/10371689#T-ND10374182) to get an AAD token and call any REST API in the PowerShell. Then check if the "Last accessed date" will change and if the API returns correctly.

Comment: The code in your sample is like the code i'm already using - i've updated the main post to reflect the code used. However, if i run this locally, using the sample you gave, i do encounter an error. I've added that to the main post, too.

Comment: The "Last Accessed" date/time did update to Feb 20th though, which is encouraging!

Comment: According to your error message, it seems that you are still running the scripts I shared in your app/program. My last suggestion is to run the scripts directly in PowerShell outside your app/program. The purpose of this is to check whether the current service principal can still access DevOps outside your app/program and obtain the token. Now that the "Last accessed date" has been updated, you can run your original program again and see if it works.

Comment: The script taken from your comment ("this ticket") was run in Powershell 7.4 on my local machine, not in the pipeline. This was what generated the error message you see in my main post.
This morning, the script that i wrote ran again in an Azure Pipeline, but did not complete successfully, and the "Last Accessed" data still says February 20th, not the 21st, as it should've.
It seems the error message holds information regarding what's really going wrong, but i don't understand it.

Comment: I've screenshotted the powershell window and added it to the main post at the bottom, so that produced the error message, so you can see the code run :)

Comment: Not sure about the error message. Running the scripts in the ticket shared by me on my side, there isn't any issue. Maybe you can try to remove the service principal from your org and add again, then check if your pipeline works. Besides, you can try to create a new service principal and use it in your program, then check if this service principal has the same issue or not.